# css position pseudo elements stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Hello** I use before & after in my element and it's work well, but the problem that when I set background-color for section the before & after will be disappear I know that this problem appear because of `z-index: -1`and I know that we can't stacking child element (before & after) above the parent element so what is the solution, I don't need to create any new elements to do this trick:

**It's what I need:**
[image]

```css
section{
    height:400px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background-color:#00fb8f;
}
.box-shadow-1{
    height:200px;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    position:relative;
}
.box-shadow-1:before,
.box-shadow-1:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.box-shadow-1:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="box-shadow-1">
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the `box-shadow-1`'s parent a `z-index`, like this

```
.col-lg-11.col-lg-offset-1 {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

*I also adjusted your pseudo elements a little, so you get the shadow like the posted image*

Stack snippet

```css
section{
    height:400px;
    padding:30px 0;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
}
.col-lg-11.col-lg-offset-1 {        /*  added rule  */
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
.box-shadow-1{
    height:150px;
    background-color:#00fb8f;
    position:relative;
}
.box-shadow-1:before,
.box-shadow-1:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 30px 20px #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 30px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.box-shadow-1:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="box-shadow-1">
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `z-index` value for the parent of `box-shadow-1`.

```css
section{
    height:400px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background-color:#00fb8f;
}
.box-shadow-1-parent {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}
.box-shadow-1 {
    height:200px;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    position:relative;
}
.box-shadow-1:before,
.box-shadow-1:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.box-shadow-1:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1 box-shadow-1-parent">
                <div class="box-shadow-1">
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: thank you for trying helping me, the pseudo must be above the section and under the grey element!!

Comment: Yeah, that definitely wasn't clear in the original question. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Don't understand why you got down voted, so I upvoted :)

Comment: @LGSon thanks, might have been before I updated? Right back at ya ;)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
section{
    height:400px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background-color:#00fb8f;
}
.box-shadow-1{
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
}
.box-shadow-1 > div {
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.box-shadow-1:before,
.box-shadow-1:after {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}
.box-shadow-1:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="box-shadow-1">
                    <div>Hello World</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I know this solution but I don't prefer it because I don't need to add more elements, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this is to send the `<section>` to the back and then bring the parent of `.box-shadow1` forward like this,

```
section{
    height:400px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background-color:#00fb8f;
    z-index: -2;
}

.col-lg-11 {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

---

As you can see below you achieve what you are looking for.

```css
section{
    height:400px;
    padding:50px 0;
    background-color:#00fb8f;
    z-index: -2;
}

.col-lg-11 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.box-shadow-1{
    height:200px;
    background-color:#e8e8e8;
    position:relative;
}

.box-shadow-1:before,
.box-shadow-1:after {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 25px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  top: 80%;
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color:#ff0000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #000;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #777;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-8deg);
  transform: rotate(-8deg);
}

.box-shadow-1:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(8deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(8deg);
  transform: rotate(8deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-lg-offset-1">
                <div class="box-shadow-1">
                    Hello World
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No need for `z-index` on `section`, it is enough on the `box-shadow-1`'s parent, combined with `position: relative`